# How can I recursively copy all pdf files in a directory (and it's subdirectories) into a single output directory?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a directory containing a large number of PDF files, some of which are in subdirectories (which can extend several layers deep).  I would like to move all files matching `*.pdf` into a single output folder named `papers`.

How can I do this?

Comment: How would you like to handle the case there are two files `a/x.pdf` and `b/x.pdf`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use `bash` in a recent version, you can profit from the `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
mv **/*.pdf papers/
```

Comment: Bash versions greater than 4.0-alpha http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar

Answer (score 31):

```
  find /bunchopdfs -name "*.pdf" -exec mv {} /papers \;
```

Here's a test I did

```
$ ls -R
.:
a  aaa bbb.pdf  pdfs

./a:
foo.pdf

./pdfs:
```

Notice the file "aaa bbb.pdf".

```
$ find . -name "*pdf" -exec mv {} pdfs \;
$ ls -R
.:
a  pdfs

./a:

./pdfs:
aaa bbb.pdf  foo.pdf
```

Comment: Beautiful! +1 !

Comment: Don't you need to quote `"{}"` to deal with file names containing spaces?

Comment: @terdon: Actually, no you don't (though that sort of problem does catch me out sometimes). See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
find -print0 /directory/with/pdfs -iname "*.pdf" | xargs -0 mv -t /papers
```

(similar to another answer but I prefer pipe/xargs/mv ... more intuitive for me)

FYI, I did the above one-line script successfully on multiple directories and multiple pdf files.

Comment: xargs has the issue of "spaces in filenames" that -exec doesn't. You can mediate this somewhat by adding args `-print0` to your find, and `-0` to xargs.

Comment: @RichHomolka see changed answer. (Thanks for the tip. That is really useful!)

Comment: Have you ever tried that? Looks like you need to add the "-print0" at the end of the find command

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows command line (cmd.exe), you can use:

```
for /F "usebackq delims==" %j IN (`dir /s /b *.pdf`) do copy "%j" c:\target_dir
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Thank you for your answer, but the question specifically requests a linux solution.

Comment: It is still marvelous that windows can do that too!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only searching one directory deep, you could do:

```
mkdir <destination>
mv */*.pdf <destination>
```

where `<destination>` stands for some directory. `mv` will not automatically create a directory for you.